# How to remove Baidu's cookie

Tags: cookies

How to remove viglink & baidu's cookie.

I create a empty html file and testing on my Chrome

I notice there are 3 files is reading from baidu 2 from viglink

I use Chrome Network to check this what files are reading.

I'm not sure what are those files for, r those secure?

I check cookies and try to remove it from Chrome

but it comeing back.

```
hm.js?3d143f0a07b6487f65609d8411e5464f
hm.baidu.com

vglnk.js
cdn.viglink.com/api

ping?format=jsonp&key=084c74521c465af0d8f08b63422103cc&loc=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fz.php&v=1&ref=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&jsonp=vglnk_jsonp_13800321595965
api.viglink.com/api

hm.gif?cc=1&ck=1&cl=32-bit&ds=1920x1080&ep=59502%2C7996&et=3&fl=11.8&ja=1&ln=zh-TW&lo=0&lt=1380031859&nv=0&rnd=632137474&si=3d143f0a07b6487f65609d8411e5464f&st=4&su=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&v=1.0.47&lv=3&u=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fz.php
hm.baidu.com

hm.gif?cc=1&ck=1&cl=32-bit&ds=1920x1080&et=0&fl=11.8&ja=1&ln=zh-TW&lo=0&lt=1380031859&nv=0&rnd=998891479&si=3d143f0a07b6487f65609d8411e5464f&st=4&su=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2F&v=1.0.47&lv=3
hm.baidu.com
```

Comment: Contents and location of the page, plus mention of the framework/server might be nice.

Comment: What are you talking about?